# Локализация Android приложения

Tags: android-studio, локализация, radiobutton

Я бедный недопрограммист одиночка, начал изучать Android studio и пытаюсь в своём приложении сделать локализацию. Я искал в интернете ответ на свой вопрос, и если находил что-то похожее ничего не понимал. Поэтому вынужден обратится к вам мастерам программирования, к людям которые родились программистами а не стали ими. Заранее прошу прощения за такого холопа как я, который не смог найти ответа на нужный мне вопрос. Спасибо!

И так у меня есть 6 RadioButton, и 6 values с разными языками как мне сделать так чтобы при нажатии на RadioButton выбирался нужный мне язык

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3d3b35">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textLGEN"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LGEN"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:checked="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textLGRU"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LGRU"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textLGDEU"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LGDEU"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textLGFR"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LGFR"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textLGESP"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LGESP"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textLGUA"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/LGEUA"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Что и куда писать в MainActivity.java

Comment: См. здесь: https://android-tools.ru/dokumentaciya/palette/radiobutton/   или видео здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-V5S6pvegM

Answer (score 1):

Переоформите, пожалуйста, Вопрос. Он на 95% состоит из воды и разговоров/кода о RadioButton, в то время как вопрос-то к ним отношения не имеет...

Вы можете изменить текущий язык приложения следующим способом:

```
public void setLocale (String lang, Context context) {
        Locale locale = new Locale (lang);
        Locale.setDefault (locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration ();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getResources ().updateConfiguration (config, context.getResources ().getDisplayMetrics ());
}
```

где lang - идентификатор языка. "ru", "fr" и т.п. Все ресурсы, которые уже были использованы, останутся на своих местах. То есть та активити, которая уже создана, те фрагменты, которые уже прикреплены, будут на старом языке. Чтобы они обновились - надо "переинфлейтить". Вполне работает вариант просто взять интент вашей активити и запустить ее заново

```
Intent intent = activity.getIntent ();
activity.finish ();
activity.startActivity (intent);
```

Если у вас нет проблем с восстановлением состояния, активити перезапустится и все будет на новом языке.

Можно сохранять выбранный язык и устанавливать его при запуске до выполнения setContentView, или на SplashActivity